# Problems with QtXQuery in qt 5.12.8

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to read xml tags from a document using QtXQuery. Works out fine besides a '\n'-char that is attached to each query-result. Moreover using the last()-statement on a collection returns the expected number of items in the collection with a trailing repetition + '\n'.
[Why QXmlQuery seem to add a ` \n` to results? (and how to solve it?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198868/why-qxmlquery-seem-to-add-a-n-to-results-and-how-to-solve-it) suggest to use a QStringList and only take the first item into account, yet this does not seem to work with my setup as using a QStringList on query.evaluateTo(&qsl) fails to return any results. So: my question is if this is a bug in libqt5xmlPatterns5 or if my implementation is the reason for this behavior? Am I missing some details on how to use QtXmlQuery?
So here is the piece of code:

1. get_tag_value:

   ```
   static lib_int_err_t get_tag_value(QString *result, QUrl schema_file, QString xml_file_name, QString var_name, QString query_str)
   {
       lib_int_err_t ret_code = LIE_OK;
       QFile *xml_f= new QFile(xml_file_name);
       xml_f->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
       if(result!=nullptr){
           result->clear();
           QXmlSchema xmlschema;
           // QStringList *results = new QStringList();
           xmlschema.load(schema_file);
           QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XQuery10, xmlschema.namePool());
           query.bindVariable(var_name, xml_f);
           query.setQuery(query_str);
           query.evaluateTo(result);
           // result->append(results->first());
           ret_code = LIE_OK;
       }
       else{
           ret_code = LIE_XML_MALFORMED;
       }
       xml_f->close();
       return ret_code;

   }
   ```
2. The input query string:

   ```
   'declare copy-namespaces no-preserve, inherit; declare variable $" + var_name + " external; doc($" + var_name + ")" + "//procLib/last()" '
   ```
3. The schema used for data description:

   ```
    <xs:element name="toolConfig">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="processingLibsSettings">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="interfaceSchemaDef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="interfaceSchemaPath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="processingLibsInstances">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:element name="procLib" minOccurs="0">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="procLibConfigName" type="xs:string"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="procLibConfigPath" type="xs:string"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="procLibName" type="xs:string"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="procLibPath" type="xs:string"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="installDir" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with a workaround:

```
results=results.remove('\n');
results=results.split(' ')[0];
```

not really nice, but it works...